# center one div above two other divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to achieve this situation:
[image: Align a div in center of page above 2 other divs]

The page contains 4 divs in total. The main layer is divided in 3 divs.
Above div1 and div2, another div(div4) must be floating above them in the middle of these 2 divs.

current code:

```
body {
position:relative;
}

div1 {
 // nothing
}

div2 {
 // nothing
}

div3 {
 // nothing
}

div4 {
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 top: 550px;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 50px;
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a heads up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: but you want the content to fit around div4 ? That would be impossible

Comment: you could always place div4 inside div1 and try margin bottom on div 4

Comment: Do you mean you want half of div4 above div1, and the other half above div2? Independently of the heights of all elements?

Comment: div 1,2 and 3 are on layer 1, div 4 is on layer 2 but floats above div1 and 2 in the middle of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is just how to get that layout this can help:

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  height: 33.3%;
}
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: blue;
}
.four {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  top: 17%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

---

But this is just visual boxes, if you have more requirements can be a little tricky.

Comment: div 4 contains a form

Comment: @Mr.Goose is better if you include more details on your question and alll your html code .... this answer provides the solution for the img you post so maybe it's better if you can be more specific

Comment: Just a few tidy ups. Thanks Danko!

Comment: That printscreen looks nice @Mr.Goose glad to help U a little bit :P