# overlay div in the middle of two divs which don't have fixed height

Tags: html, css

I would like to overlay a `<div>` on top of two `<div>`s, and layout it in between these two.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196741/center-one-div-above-two-other-divs) SO answer is very close to what I would like to achieve but the answer is not very practical because it explicitly sets the height of the underlying and overlapping `<div>`s. I would like a solution in which these heights are not set, but rather derived from the situation.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF6d7.png)

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xerroxcopy/ktqwae92/40/) (I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.0) is what I have tried so far. This is fairly close, but the `.second` `<div>`'s margin-top is set manually, resulting in the top edge of .second div not touching the .first div's bottom edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap `.overlay` in a div and set `position: relative;`.

Then, on the overlay: `position: absolute; transform: translateY(-50%);`, it will position relative to the top of the bottom div so that, regardless how much text there is in `.first`, or what size the screen is, their position will remain intact.

```css
.first {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  z-index: 0;
}

.second {
  background-color: rgba(124, 150, 80, 0.9);
  padding-top: 4em;
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  margin: 0 5em 0 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">Some text content goes here. Since the content is not fixed, I don't want to set a fixed height. Some text content goes here. Since the content is not fixed, I don't want to set a fixed height. Some text content goes here. Since the content is not fixed,
    I don't want to set a fixed height.</div>
  <div class="overlay-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay">here comes the overlay div that should come between and overlap first and second div. again, the height of this div is not explicitly set.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">Some text content goes here. Since the content is not fixed, I don't want to set a fixed height.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the background of *.div1* and *.div2* are plain color, you can to somthing like this :

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 {
    background: #F19063;
}
.div2 {
    background: #A44691;
}
.div3 {
    position: relative;
    background: #70BB86;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
.div3:before {
    content: '';
    background: #F19063;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
}
.div3:after {
    content: '';
    background: #A44691;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br></div>
  <div class="div3">Lorem <br>Lorem <br></div>
  <div class="div2">Lorem <br>Lorem <br>Lorem <br></div>
</div>
```

PS: you need to handle to overflow of *.div3:before* and *.div3:after*.